# How to access Jenkins secrets directory?

Tags: docker, permissions

Yesterday I installed Jenkins into my home directory. I used Docker on Ubuntu

```
docker run \ -u root \ --rm \ -d \ -p 8081:8080 \ -p 50000:50000 \ -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ jenkinsci/blueocean
```

I run container and opened it in firefox browser.
Now I have troubles to unlock Jenkins.
These are permissions

```
drwx------   4 root root  4096 мај 29 17:14 secrets/
```

If I change permissions,will it make my machine vulnerable?

If I inspect container,my Mounts

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "f2bc2476f886b6ad57a04a3c886743456ca41d48dfd7074b027e2b2109cf79ee",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/f2bc2476f886b6ad57a04a3c886743456ca41d48dfd7074b027e2b2109cf79ee/_data",
        "Destination": "/var/jenkins_home",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
```

But `/var/jenkins_home` does not exist in `/var`

Anyway If I use `sudo su -`, I can not manipulate directory at all.
How to fix this?

Comment: Where you try to find `/var/jenkins_home`, host or container?

Comment: I tried at host,it seems I should exec container.

Comment: yes............